# Rails .try returning nil when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone explain the following behavior? They both should return the same.

```
@properties.filtros_hash
=> {"casa"=>"sim"}

@properties.try(:filtros_hash)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@properties, in my case, was an instance of a SimpleDelegator. Something like this:

```
class PropertiesDecorator < SimpleDelegator

    def filtros_hash
        {some_hash: 'hash'}
    end

end

@properties = PropertiesDecorator.new(@properties)
```

Having that in mind, and reading [Rails's documentation about `.try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-try), I found out this:

> Please also note that try is defined on Object. Therefore, it won't
>   work with instances of classes that do not have Object among their
>   ancestors, like direct subclasses of BasicObject. For example, using
>   try with SimpleDelegator will delegate try to the target instead of
>   calling it on the delegator itself.

So, that explains this highly unexpected behavior, since even tough PropertiesDecorator have a `filtros_hash` instance method, by using .try the `filtros_hash` is being delegated to @properties (ActiveRecord) where there is no such method.